# how to include environment when submitting an automl experiment in azure machine learning

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service, azure-sdk-python

I use code like below to create an AutoML object to submit an experiment for classification training

```
automl_settings = {
       "n_cross_validations": 2,
       "primary_metric": 'accuracy',
       "enable_early_stopping": True,
       "experiment_timeout_hours": 1.0,
       "max_concurrent_iterations": 4,
       "verbosity": logging.INFO,
   }

   automl_config = AutoMLConfig(task = 'classification',
                               compute_target = compute_target,
                               training_data = train_data,
                               label_column_name = label,
                               **automl_settings
                               )

   ws = Workspace.from_config()
   experiment = Experiment(ws, "your-experiment-name")
   run = experiment.submit(automl_config, show_output=True)
```

I want to include my conda yml file (like below) in my experiment submission.

```
env = Environment.from_conda_specification(name='myenv', file_path='conda_dependencies.yml')
```

However, I don't see any environment parameter in [AutoMLConfig class documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azureml-train-automl-client/azureml.train.automl.automlconfig.automlconfig?view=azure-ml-py) (similar to what environment parameter does in `ScriptRunConfig`) or find any example how to do so.

I notice after the experiment is submitted, I get message like this

```
Running on remote.
No run_configuration provided, running on aml-compute with default configuration
```

Is `run_configuration` used for specifying environment? If so, how do I provide run_configuration in my **AutoML experiment run**?

Thank you.

Comment: can you explain why you need a custom environment?

Comment: I don't believe that's required. That may be how to set up the compute target - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-auto-train-remote

Comment: The public AML environment I used the SDK was upgraded from 1.18.0 to 1.19.0 (w/o warning) and now code stops working with weird errors. I thought to pass in 1.18.0 conda yml file as a workaround. This is allowed in model deployment but not in experiment run. 
I was able to uninstall sdk 1.19.0 in the notebook environment, but there is no sdk 1.18.0 to be found for installation. I'm at my wit's end.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to fix the issues associated with the sdk 1.19.0 upgrade in the AML environment I use, thus no need for the `workaround` (ie. pass in a SDK 1.18.0 conda environment file to AutoML experiment run) I was thinking about. My original question no longer needs an answer, I just want to add this note in case someone else has the same question later on.

I still don't know why AutoML experiment run has no option to pass in a conda environment file. It would be nice if a reason is given in the AML documentation.